# Calling Client side by server side Thru Button Command

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have simple code like this... as follow...

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="AlinmaWebApp._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #formHt
        {
            height: 284px;
        }
        .DivStyle
        {
            height :250px;
            background-color :Green ;
            display : block;
        }

    </style>

<script language="javascript" type ="text/javascript" >

    function TryClose() {
        document.getElementById("DivBah").style.height = '1px';
        document.getElementById("DivBah").style.display = 'none';
        return;
    }
</script>


</head>
<body onload="TakeIT() return;" >
    <form id="formHt" runat="server">
    <div id="DivBah" class="DivStyle" >
        Just Try if this part will Collapse or not</div>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="TryClose()"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

That gave me Error message like =>  "TryClose" is not a part of "default_._ASPX"
What is possible error on this type of coding?
Since i always use this type in Simple ASP Program before.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using vs 2008 (.NET 3.5) use OnClientClick instead.

The error that you got is pretty logical. The "OnClick" attribute is used to wire up handlers **"Server Side Handlers**" to the click event. Because those handlers are server-side handlers, VS took a look at your .vb file that is mapped to your aspx page and found no method with the name `TryClose()`.

`TryClose()` here is a client-side function; in order to use it as a handler to the click event "on the client" you need to wire it up using the `OnClientClick` attribute. 
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="TryClose()"/>
```

OnClick used for server side click event.